# CORS Error when adding a parameter in an Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, cors

I can't at all figure out why this is not working.

I have an express app hosted on Heroku that basically does this

```
var urlMetadata = require('url-metadata')

var express = require('express')

var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products', function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({
        msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'
    })
})

app.get('/prod/:url', function (req, res, next) {

    var url = decodeURI(req.params.url);

    urlMetadata(url).then(
        function (metadata) {
            res.json({
                metadata
            });
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        })
})
```

Client side

```
    axios
      .get(`https://git.heroku.com/egosmos-meta.git/prod`, {
        params: {
          url,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });

    axios
      .get(`https://egosmos-meta.herokuapp.com/products`)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
```

And this is what I'm getting

[image]

So `/products` works, but `/prod/:url` throws a CORS error

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`params` in Axios defines the query parameters, eg `?url=http://example.com` but your Express app is expecting a [route parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters).

Change your client-side code to the following

```js
axios.get(`https://git.heroku.com/egosmos-meta.git/prod/${encodeURIComponent(url)}`)
```

You get a CORS error because you have no route for `/prod?url=...` so the CORS middleware isn't kicking in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. your explanation makes sense and was useful. But it unfortunately didn't solve my issue. I'm wondering what's wrong.

Comment: @Albrich Please update the code and error messages / screenshots reported in your question

Answer (score 0):

try using the corsOption..

var cors = require('cors')

var corsOptions = {
origin: 'https://git.heroku.com',
optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

Also if for the axios try
axios.get(`https://git.heroku.com/egosmos-meta.git/prod/${url}`).then()